# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two types of user in my database one is user and another is admin. I have made user and admin login and both of them works. I have use [Authorize] in some user classes and whenever I browse that link it will automatically redirect towards user login. Now, here comes the problem. I have used [Authorize] in some admin class also, hoping to redirect toward admin login but it will redirect towards user login.

Web.Config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/LoginView" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

AdminRetrieveCrimeReportController.cs

```
using OnlineCrimeReportingSystem.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OnlineCrimeReportingSystem.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class AdminRetrieveCrimeReportController : Controller
{
    private OnlineCrimeReportingSystemEntities2 context = new OnlineCrimeReportingSystemEntities2();
    // GET: AdminRetrieveCrimeReport
    public ActionResult AdminRetrieveCrimeReportView()
    {
        var model = context.Crimes.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult DeactiveCrime(int id)
    {
        var crime = context.Crimes.Find(id);
        crime.Status = false;

        context.Entry(crime).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("AdminRetrieveCrimeReportView");
    }
}
}
```

This page AdminRetrieveCrimeReportView should redirect toward AdminLogin but it will redirect toward Userlogin please help me.